# How to get the mapped file object name from the objecthandle in C++?

Tags: c++, createfile, file-mapping

I am working on a project where I need to decrypt some media files which are mapped to memory by a process. I have successfully hooked the `CreateFileW()` and `MappedViewOfFile()` functions. I need to verify the "name of mapping object" inside the `MappedViewOfFile()` function. I just have the handle of the object and I am not sure how to retrieve its name. Please see the below code for a better understanding of my question. I have hooked already the read and write functions of the other process. That works pretty well, but when another process writes to other files using the above file, it fails..

```
LPVOID WINAPI MapViewHooked(  
__in HANDLE hFileMappingObject,
 __in DWORD  dwDesiredAccess,
 __in DWORD  dwFileOffsetHigh,
 __in DWORD  dwFileOffsetLow,
 __in SIZE_T dwNumberOfBytesToMap   ) 
{ 
//string pszobjectnamefrom handle=some_function(hFileMappingObject);//here i am stucked
if(pszobjectnamefrom=="MYOBJECT")
??How to update the data in memory i have the code to decrypt the buffer

}
```

Comment: If i copy the file content using ReadFile than decrypt the content and write to a file and return it's handle to that process everything works well. but that process taking a long because of the big size of media files.

Comment: See [Obtaining a File Name From a File Handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/obtaining-a-file-name-from-a-file-handle) on MSDN. It provides an example of [`GetMappedFileName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getmappedfilenamew)

Comment: Hi Remy, I have checked the example provided by MSDN this is for the FileName from the File Handle. I have to get the "MappedObjectName" from its handle.

Comment: What's the difference? AFAIK, an object only has one name. Whether that name is a file path or something else

Comment: I tried to get the name from the above example it returns bizarre characters.

Comment: then you likely didn't do correctly. Please [edit] your post to show the code you tried.